# Updating nested user controls from parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form `Form1` and 2 user controls - `MyUserControl` and `NestedUserControl`.

The `NestedUserControl` has a `TextBox` named `textBox1`. The `NestedUserControl` is a child of `MyUserControl`. I need to update the 
 `TextBox` text from the form. I have used properties for this as shown below:

**Form1.cs:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myUserControl1.NestedText = "Hi";
    }
}
```

**MyUserControl.cs:**

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string NestedText
    {
        get { return nestedUserControl1.ThisText; }
        set { nestedUserControl1.ThisText = value; }
    }
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**NestedUserControl:**

```
public partial class NestedUserControl : UserControl
{
    public NestedUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ThisText 
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to update the `TextBox` in `NestedUserControl`? Other way is to make NestedUserControl public and access its controls which i don't think is correct practice.

Comment: Just use data binding

Comment: Yeah, it looks ok. Usually, there is a logic in these properties. Like checking value for correctness, changing font-size, color, affect other UI things -
 all these things you have created your `UserControl` for. If your `UserControl` is just a `TextBox`, then you just don't need this `UserControl` :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: What code I have posted is only a sample as mu actual user control is way far complex than just a text box.